# Python requests/n bs4 work/doesn't work based on directory

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am very new to Python and I am running into few problems. One of them is that I have both requests and bs4 libraries installed and the problem is that they work or don't work based on where is my .py file saved. 
For eg.

- if my .py file is saved on the desktop they both work
- if my .py file is saved on Desktop/python requests won't work and
- if it is saved on C:/users/WE only beautiful soup will work but not requests will not.

I have installed both the libraries via pip. I have even removed and reinstalled them, but same problem happens. Appreciate any support.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Comment: Provide more informtion about your problem(s). Like logs. What errors did you get?

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be avoided by using something called virtual environments. It's a way of isolating your project and its dependencies and it's considered a best practice in the Python world.

Follow these steps:

1. First let's create your project folder: `mkdir myproject` and then go inside it `cd myproject`.
2. Then install the virtualenv library: `pip install virtualenv`
3. Now we need to create a new environment and then activate it: `virtualenv env` ("env" would be the environment name, you can name it however you want but most devs name it either "env" or "venv")
4. Now we activate it: `env\Scripts\activate` (remember to replace "env" if chose a different name)

Now you should see that your path is prefixed with your environment name: 
`(env) C:\Users\username\myproject`.

Now proceed to install your libraries and run your code from within the environment. You can deactivate it by typing "deactivate" and reactivate following step 4.

Hope this will help.